# How to add a display name to mail sent via SMTP

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, smtp, webmail

I am sending mail via gmail SMTP account by adding below in Global.asax file -

```
WebMail.SmtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com";
WebMail.SmtpPort = 587;
WebMail.EnableSsl = true;
WebMail.UserName = "accname@example.com";
WebMail.From = "accname@example.com";
WebMail.Password = "nopassword";
WebMail.SmtpUseDefaultCredentials = false;
```

When I send a mail through `WebMail.Send()` method, the mail is sent properly, but the recieved mail always has name - "accname". What I want it to show it as some other name - let's say "Name". How should I do that here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can set the `From` property to include the name as well as the email address:

```
WebMail.From = "Your Name <accname@example.com>";
```

You may need to surround the name with quotes, for example:

```
WebMail.From = "\"Your Name\" <accname@example.com>";
```

Comment: It throws this exception - The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required.

Comment: I think that is the actual account id as per WebMail class documentation.

Comment: This is working fine. I did not require to quote the name. Thanks. But this seems like a hack. Do you know if this will work even if gmail is not the mail server?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using appsettings.json, you have to give the Email Configuration like this:

```json
"EmailConfiguration" : {
    "SmtpServer": "smtp.gmail.com",
    "SmtpPort": 587,
    "UserName": "accname@example.com",
    "From": "Name To Display<accname@example.com>",
    "Password": "nopassword",
    "EnableSsl": true
}
```